# why git commits are not in range between date of their tags

Tags: git, date, version, commit, release

when I make `git log --pretty=oneline 2.0.7..2.1 --  wp-includes/functions.php` as an exemple between two tags (releases),
I found a number of commits 106 commits realised between them.
But it is weird when I see the version1: 2.0.7 released on *2007-01-15 20:51:28 +0000* and the version2: 2.1 released on *2007-01-23 02:23:20 +0000*.
And the commits I found are between **2006-02-09 10:03:48 +0000** and **2007-01-16 18:41:05 +0000**

Could anyone explain me this phenomena ?

Comment: Woudln't know but would it be possible that a merging commits / cherry-picking would apply a previous commit to an already existing - and recente - branch, along side its original date? Waiting for an answer aswell, interesting question

Comment: This is a total guess: but I'm going to say there was a commit added on `2006-02-09` that wasn't merged into whichever branch you're on (I assume `master`) until after `2.0.7`.  Ie, someone had a feature branch that was "worked" on for 11 months before it was finally merged, hence it'll show up in your `git log`

Comment: as I see too for other versions, 2.0.6 released on 2007-01-06 04:24:41 +0000, and 2.0.5 released on 2006-10-27 22:42:01 +0000, 2.0.4 released on 2006-07-29 02:25:19 +0000, 2.0.3 released on 2006-06-02 17:44:49 +0000, 2.0.2 released on 2006-06-02 17:43:25 +0000, 2.0.1 released on 2006-02-01 22:11:17 +0000 and 2.0 released on 2005-12-26 21:35:22 +0000. The repository I am using is Wordpress

Comment: I verify them, they are all on the same branch, so I think your point is not applied here :/. It still not responded...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, every commit has *two* time stamps in it: the author time stamp, and the committer time stamp.  Typically these two are the same, but that's not required.  Use `git log --pretty=fuller` to see both.

Second, these time stamps are literally arbitrary (within some range: they are limited to values Git can represent internally).  They *default* to whatever is set on your computer, at the time you create a commit, but your computer's clock can be off, perhaps wildly so, and anyone can tell Git to set some particular time other than the clock-time.

Last, the `X..Y` notation *does not* mean *between*.  See my answer to your previous question, [How to find commit responsible by adding a file index (blob)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49098004/1256452).  Pay close attention to the various possible graph shapes, and consider that `X..Y` really means `Y ^X`: include any commit reachable from commit `Y`, including `Y` itself, while excluding all commits reachable from `X`, including `X` itself.

Comment: Thank you for your response

Comment: I will describe very well for your response in https://stackoverflow.com/q/49098004/1256452 what I have as a problem and why I wanted to explore blob of files.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you are right Philip Pittle, I found that there was a branch created as shown in picture. [image]